# jQuery element sizing doesn't work as supposed to on live site, works on local version. Chromium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar that equals the height of another element, this works fine locally but it's quite erratic on the live version.

On the initial load, in Chromium, the sidebar doesn't reach all the way to the bottom of the container, only after I resize the browser will it reach all the way down.

In Firefox this problem does not occur.

The code that changed the element's height is:

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var documentHeight = $('#contentWrapper').height();
     $('#menuOption').css('height',documentHeight + 'px');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var documentHeight = $('#contentWrapper').height();
        $('#menuOption').css('height',documentHeight + 'px');
    }).resize();   
});
```

A link to my live site is [here](http://lartmagazine.co.uk/)

To re-create the problem scroll down to the bottom of the page and hit refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of a given element can change based on stylesheets and images within the element. In your case, you're retrieving the height on dom ready, which typically happens before all images and stylesheets are done loading. The reason this problem didn't present itself on your local server is because the network delay between your local server and your browser is likely non-existent (0ms), meaning the images/stylesheets are done loading before the dom is ready.

To solve this, wait till the window load event, which happens after all assets (stylesheets and images) are done loading.

```
jQuery(window).on("load",function(){
    // do stuff
});
```